# Does command-line stop programs launched in command window when command window is closed?

Tags: java, windows, command-line

When launching and executable jar from the command window, is the jar attached to that window? So when I close the command line the program stops running, or will it continue in the background?

If so, `System.out.println()` should that print to the command window open if I'd closed the first command window?

This is in Windows (server 2012)

Comment: On what OS are you running these programs?

Comment: Windows, will update text body.

Comment: @PeterTillemans The question has been tagged with `windows`

Comment: Can't you test the behavior by yourself?

Comment: I am, and I am under the assumption that the processes were attached to the window that opened them. I couldn't find any information easily to clarify this so I had to ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.exe` is attached to the current running command shell or the batch script that launched it. `javaw.exe` will start it as a separate windows program without that attachment. Using `javaw` is approximately the same as running `java -jar xyz.jar &` on Linux.

Comment: Still doesn't answer `If so, System.out.println() should that print to the command window open if I'd closed the first command window?`

Comment: Why would it print to the current open window if the one that spawned it is closed? It would have no way of knowing about the other open command shells.

Comment: I totally agree. But I simply quoted the question from the OP which has not been addressed in your answer. Your comment should probably be a part of the answer (even though what it says is obvious).

Comment: java.exe isn't attached to cmd.exe. It's attached to the same console (conhost.exe) as the parent cmd shell, unless you use the `start` command to make the child attach to a new console. A third option is running as a detached process (i.e. not attached to any console), but cmd doesn't provide a built-in for that. You'd need another scripting language such as Python.